# Is there a way to specify in google tests that certain tests need to have passed for this test

Tags: c++, googletest

Is there a way in google tests to indicate that a certain test should have passed. I would like to specify some pre-reqs to a test.
Example

```
TEST(Category, Eat)
{
}
TEST(Category, Sleep)
{
}

TEST(Category, Grow)
{
   //Eat and Sleep tests must have passed.
}
```

Is there a way for me to indicate that Eat and Sleep tests should have passed in Test Grow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use fatal assertions (ASSERT_...) instead of non fatal ones (EXPECT_...) in "Eat" and "Sleep". If you add "Grow" after "Eat" and "Sleep", it won't be performed if any of these fail.